# Layout is shrinking when keyboard opens android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am working on an app and i have set

```
enter code here
<activity
        android:name=".ui.base.BaseActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden|adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"/>
```

and in this activity i am using different fragments and than also all layouts are shrinking. Please help if you want any codes please let me know.
Thanks
I am sharing you my screen image please check.[image]

This layout is home activity

```
enter code here
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:isScrollContainer="false">

<include
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    layout="@layout/actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/base_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</FrameLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/tab_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!--android:background="@color/tab_background_color"-->


    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab_1"
        layout="@layout/activity_base_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab_2"
        layout="@layout/activity_base_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab_3"
        layout="@layout/activity_base_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab_4"
        layout="@layout/activity_base_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab_5"
        layout="@layout/activity_base_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add your layout code

Comment: I have added my xml code please check.

Comment: make your root view(linear layout) to scroll view and add the linear layout to its child of scrollview

Comment: I did but then the layout is getting scrolled, i dont want that it should be fixed because there is actionbar on top and one fixed layout at bottom

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest

```
<activity
android:name="com.companyname.applicationname"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
```

If you are using ScrollView add this

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:isScrollContainer="false">
```

Comment: i am not using scrollview